# POSTGRESQL query: query does not return result if there is blank space, and will return result if using underscore

Tags: postgresql

Could you please help for this strange issue?
i have a postgresql table database, when i try to query, the result is empty:

```
select * from abdata_entry where abcolumn_display='Ag antam' and job_reference='jr19112018' and id_sample='9'
```

As you can see, there space between  "Ag antam" .. this query will return no result.

But if i add underscore like this Ag_antam, the query will return result as expected.
Actual string in the table is Ag antam without underscore.
Here are the screenshot:

[image: result after add underscore]

[image: no result without underscore]

Comment: My guess is that the reason your current query is not matching is because one (or more) of the three fields in your `WHERE` clause actually has extra whitespace.  The reason why `Ag_antam` matches, is because those other records _don't_ exhibit this whitespace problem.

Comment: could you please check the screenshot. as you can see,  there is no space in the other fields.. and why if i add underscore it works

Comment: My guess is it actually does contain an underscore, you just think it doesn't because the cell view in pgadmin sort of hides the underscore so you think it's a space. Try copying the actual cell value from the result and paste it somewhere and see.

Comment: @ssffzzxx Read the Euro trash comment, which seems like a good guess.  You have some artifact at work here, which maybe you can't see.

Comment: Ah.. you re correct. thank you very much.. thanks you. After long hours typing code.. i can not see clearly.. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks  @eurotrash.. thanks a lot for helping me .. it is so much appreciated.

Comment: @ssffzzxx No problem, I've had this same issue before with being unable to see underscores in pgadmin so suspected it was probably the same.